# Use AngularJS in China

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, cdn

I got a small angularJS based website that is supposed to run internationally. One important location is China. While the website works fine here (Germany), I cannot get it to work in China. 
I am currently using proxys to confirm that, but I also have had friends in China confirm it is not working.

Research has shown that googleapis is blocked in China. So I've tried to use it locally which also did not work. I've also tried other CDNs.

Now I just randomly checked angularJs-Demo pages (e.g. for various plugins on github). None of them works with a chinese proxy.

What Am I missing here? How can this be fixed?

Comment: You can download the js/css file and load it from your server instead of using cdn.

Comment: Try hosting all JavaScript dependencies on your own hosting, alongside your own scripts.

Comment: is your ip blocked by GFW, if so you need to setup an vpn tunel in and out of the GFW.

Comment: I tried to load the files from the server with no success. Since the website of interest got checked from inside China as well I doubt it is an GFW issue here.
My webspace provider also claims they are not blocking anything and cannot do a thing to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a local angular file on your server as fallback. And in your app you can use the cdn version if the cdn is available and the local fallback when is not:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.angular || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: That's the problem. I am doing so, but it doesn't help. I've tried a couple angular seeds to make sure it's not any issue with the other code. I replaced the googleapis call with a local angular file on the server, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two CDNs that are not blocked in China:

https://www.jsdelivr.com/

https://www.bootcdn.cn/

The second one is located in China so I would recommend it if you want to have lower load time.